# Binance API shows wrong data compare to website

Tags: rest

Just discovered that [Binance API](https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-official-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md) is showing the wrong data compare to their website.

Maybe I did something wrongly but still confused.

Here is the string - https://api.binance.com/api/v1/klines?symbol=ATOMBTC&interval=1d&limit=1

It's taking a data for 24hours(1day) of ATOMBTC asset. Everything is correct in this data, price, open, close, high, Volume in USD. Only Volume in BTC is wrong. On string it shows a
"122.60368510" at this moment, but on [Binance website](https://binance.com) it shows 350 of 24h Volume.

Why it's like that and how to find correct BTC Volume from API?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking at 1d klines, which start at 12:00am utc time and end 24 hours later.

What's displayed on their site is past 24 hour volume.

So for example if it is 6:00pm UTC time, the 1d endpoint is going to show the past 18 hours of volume since 12:00am, whereas their sites 24 hour volume will show volume since 6:00pm the previous day.

If you want to come close to their site volume, try summing the volumes in

https://api.binance.com/api/v1/klines?symbol=ATOMBTC&interval=5m&limit=288